# Overwriting locked files with Move then Copy

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I am trying to write a program that will be used to apply updates to an application. Due to the nature of the application some of the files will become locked (primarily by IIS) and cannot be overwritten using `File.Copy(target)`. When performing the task manually our support team will often copy the files using windows explorer which unlocks the file allowing them to copy the new one in.

Why does this work when doing it with Windows Explorer and why does it fail so miserably when doing it in code?

By code that I am using is roughly the following:

```
File.Move( target, tempPath )
File.Copy( source, target )
```

With a unit test that opens and locks a file that you then attempt to overwrite:

```
var source = "c:\\source.txt";
var target = "c:\\target.txt";
var temp = "c:\\temp\\fake-target.txt";

using ( var lockedFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite( target ) ) {
    File.Move( target, temp )
    File.Copy( source, target )
}
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It isn't very clear exactly what is working with Windows Explorer. Obviously Explorer is just another application, and it does give you "sorry!" errors if you attempt to move/delete locked files just like any other.

Comment: Actually it completely works. If you try to delete file it will fail but if you try to move or rename the file it will succeed. After the file is renamed you can copy in your new file over where the locked file was before. It may be that the application locking the files is not exclusively locking the file but instead just preventing the copy operation.

Comment: @smaclell: Why don't you try to lock a file as in your unit test until a key is pressed and see how Explorer handles that then?

Comment: Good suggestion. 

I tried all combinations of `System.IO.FileAccess` and `System.IO.FileShare`. Only `System.IO.FileShare.Delete` allowed you to move the file. This must be the way the file are locked by IIS unless there is something else that it is doing that is not standard.

Comment: @smaclell: For extra info, you can hook Process Monitor into your process/Win Explorer to see what API calls it makes and what they return: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: I will have to try that, thanks for your great suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your *temp* filename is invalid, it is missing an extra backslash.

Renaming files that are in use works for files that have a memory mapped file created for them.  Like .exe and .dll files that are loaded in a process.  It does not work for files that you open with a FileStream.  That would be rather bad, Windows wouldn't be able to update the metadata for the file when the file is closed.  Like the file size and last written date.

This should be good enough for applying updates, your code snippet simply doesn't emulate the same operation well enough.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move locked files, neither in an application nor in the Windows Explorer. The usual way to perform an update while the software is running is to write everything to temporary files (e.g. program.exe.temp). When the update is complete, you exit the application, replace all original files with the temporary files (possibly using a small updater program), and restart the application. This way, you can also cancel the update process (until before the last step) without having interferred with the installed version at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that where you are makes a difference.  You can get away with this locally but not remotely.  Not all OSes permit it, either.